# RiscV Array maximum and minimum

Tags: arrays, assembly, max, min, riscv

I wanted to ask how do I create an array given 10 values entered by input and then calculate the maximum and minimum I'm going crazy.
I started like this but then after the 4th value the program ends:

`.data

> Blockquote

```
str1: .asciz "MAX"
str2: .asciz "MIN"
stri: .asciz "Insert 10 integers values: "
```

.text

> Blockquote

```
la a0, stri
li a7, 1
ecall
li a7, 2
ecall
li a7, 3
ecall
li a7, 4
ecall
li a7, 5
ecall
li a7, 6
ecall
li a7, 7
ecall
li a7, 8
ecall
li a7, 9
ecall
li a7, 10
ecall`
```

Comment: `a7` holds the service number for an `ecall`, so that code is doing 10 different `ecall`s.  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I did not understand very well .. the problem is the ecalls?

Comment: Look for some sample programs to study,

Comment: Then why can I only enter the first four values but then the program ends?

Comment: That's not a program.  All it does is crash.  There's no "fixing" it.  Look for some sample programs to study.

Comment: https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Environment-Calls - a7=4 / `ecall` is `PrintString` which expects a pointer in a0.  The earlier ecalls don't modify `a0`, apparently, so it should still have the address from `la a0, stri`.  But the first one that asks for input is a7=5 / `ecall`, `ReadInt`.  Then `ReadFloat` and `ReadDouble`, then crashing on a7=8 / `ecall` `ReadString` which wants an input pointer, but you have a0 = the first number you typed.  Single-step it in the debugger.

Comment: The C equivalent of this is `printf("%d", garbage)`  / ... 3 more printfs with different format strings / `scanf("%d", &tmp_int)` / `scanf("%f", &tmpf)` / ... / `gets(tmp_int)`.  (Actually with a length limit from `a1` which you didn't set either.)